# Error using poLCA (Cannot coerce formula in data frame)

Tags: r

I'm having a little bit of trouble with the following code:

```
    instseg <- read.csv("[NAME].csv", header=TRUE,sep=",")
    instmod<- cbind(AWSCust,BAN_All,FastGrow_all)~1 
    /*Note this is a test...the full cbind has about 12 more variables*/
    fa2clu2 <- poLCA(instseg, instmod, nclass=2, na.rm=FALSE)
```

I've loaded the poLCA package and I'm in the correct directory but I get the following error:

Error in as.data.frame.default(data) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"formula"’ to a data.frame

A version of this code worked for several other projects I did. I can pull summaries for the data frame but I'm not sure where the error is coming from.

The data frame has the following structure

```
'data.frame':   1372 obs. of  29 variables:
 $ ï..UNITID            : int  148885 177092 143853 110699 145558 151865 157298 169099 177126 177834 ...
 $ Instname             : Factor w/ 1371 levels "\"University of Maryland",..: 1209 249 641 1097 848 29 572 164 263 2 ...
 $ AWSCust              : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ BAN_All              : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ FastGrow_all         : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ ChngLives            : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ BAN_Priv             : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Priv_Growfast        : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Pub_BAN              : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ PUB_FastGrow         : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Rajiv                : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ StarRes              : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ TAM                  : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ ICLEVEL              : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ CONTROL              : int  2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ HBCU                 : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ TRIBAL               : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ LocaleType           : int  3 3 3 4 3 4 4 4 3 2 ...
 $ LocaleSize           : int  3 3 3 3 3 1 3 2 3 1 ...
 $ UGOnly               : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ ResType              : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ ResearchSchool       : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ LANDGRNT             : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ INSTSIZE             : int  1 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ ReligiouslyAffiliated: int  2 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 ...
 $ ROOM                 : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ BOARD                : int  2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ OL_CP                : int  1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ Pos_NegAssets        : int  3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
```

Any advice?

Comment: Switch your first two arguments.

Comment: Aaaaaand now I feel really dumb. Thank you.